# <img> max-height doesn't work

Tags: css, image

I need to display an image (and may be some controls near it) at the center (both horizontally and vertically) of the window, while being shrinked to screen height when happens to be bigger (all the images I have are vertical so I don't care about their width). 
The underlying content must be hidden with the background.
Code should work in browsers starting from Internet Explorer 8.

I managed to acheive everything but the latter - shrinking to screen height, which I am having problems with.

Here is how I tried to implement it (put in clauses with a resulting code below):

1. I put everything in a block with fixed positioning and setting 100% to it's width and height - for it to fill the whole window area. Successful.
2. I use table to center the image vertically, wherefore I set it's height to 100%. Successful.
3. Inside of the cell I place an image.

3a. When it's height is less then screen size the image is positioned at the center vertically. Successful.

3b. I set max-height to 100% for the image to make it fit into the screen. Unsucsessful! Image pushes the window apart to it's actual height (except of, surprisingly, IE).

Is it possible to solve the task described and what did I do wrong?

(my code:)

[view at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJ4wR/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="photoshow">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="http://s14.postimg.org/e9kwvq2m9/1031_1.jpg">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.photoshow { /* the containing block */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: pink; /* hiding the underlying content */
    }

    .photoshow table {
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; /* to center horizontally */
        }

        .photoshow td {
            height: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background: yellow; /* just for visual indication */
            }

            .photoshow img { 
                max-height: 100%;
                }
```

Comment: I can't get you, what exactly you want?

Comment: @Gaurav, I want big images to fit window height

Comment: you mean you need to fit your window height completely without caring its width? Do you want to preserve aspect ratio?

Comment: @Gaurav, yes but only when image is bigger than the window.
Yes, I do want to preserve aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/PJ4wR/2/)

```
.photoshow .big {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
    max-height:300px;
}
```

Comment: That requires tagging particular images with a certain class. Not universal.